# Find the residue of $(19^{33})(12^{17}) \mod 17$ using Fermat's Little Theorem?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Im somewhat familiar with the theorem and being able to reduce exponents to simpler forms and I also realize that I can break these two up into separate problems. But I cant quite connect the dots here. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: By Fermat $\,a\not\equiv 0\,\Rightarrow\, a^{16}\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\, a^{32}\equiv 1,\,$ so $\,a^{17}\equiv \ldots, a^{33}\equiv \ldots\pmod{17}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You begin with
$$19^{33}\cdot 12^{17} = 19^{17} \cdot 19^{16} \cdot 12^{17}$$
and Fermat's small Theorem tell you
$$a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \mod p$$
Therefore
$$19^{17} \cdot 19^{16} \cdot 12^{17} \mod 17 \equiv 19 \cdot 1 \cdot 12 \mod 17 \equiv 2 \cdot 1 \cdot (-5) \mod 17 \equiv 7 \mod 17$$

Comment: How is it you reach 2⋅1⋅(−5) ?

Comment: $19 \equiv 2 \mod 17, 12 \equiv -5 \mod 17$